# compile sass with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I am new to `npm` and encountered this scripts in `package.json` file.

```
"build": "node ./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass  src/css  -o dist/css"
```

And trying to understand this command bit by bit.

I know that this compiles sass file to `dist/css`.

But what does this `node ./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass  src/css` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically running the `node-sass` which compiles sass files from `src/css` and writing it to(output) `dist/css` file.

Whenever you install a local `npm` package using `npm install` it goes inside the `node_modules` folder.

So, the `node-sass` package is located at `node_modules/node-sass/` of your project. And the binary file(the executable file) is located inside the `bin` folder. This is kind of traditional. Most package which can be installed using the `-g` or `--global` `npm` switch has the binary inside `bin` folder.

Sometimes, the binary is just a js file sometime it's compiled bytecode.(like `.exe` files in windows)